# PHP get substring from a post

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a substring from a post blog (about 250 characters) and need to prevent that the end of the substring be inside of a tag. I would like such tag be included even if substring is larger than 250 characters.

This is an example:

Let's say we've got a post like this one:

> Defensa del título: "Es un reto, un gran reto, y creo que en el Real Madrid tenemos la oportunidad de volver a ganarla. Sabemos que es una competición muy complicada, pero nada es fácil, así que lo vamos a intentar. Iremos partido a partido y primero pensar en la fase de grupos, porque en mi opinión tenemos un grupo complicado. Veremos cómo se desarrolla la competición. Pienso en positivo: es posible volver a ganarla".Su gran temporada pasada: "En términos de títulos creo que fue posiblemente la mejor temporada de mi carrera.

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/uploads/imag1.png" />
```

> Tras ganar la UEFA Champions League, ganar la EURO con mi selección
>   fue el broche de oro para un año extraordinario. En cuanto a trofeos
>   fue la mejor, nunca he tenido una temporada mejor, tanto colectiva
>   como individualmente, porque fui el máximo goleador en la Champions
>   League y tuve un buen Campeonato de Europa. Además pudimos ganar los
>   dos títulos más importantes, por lo que fue un excelente curso para
>   mí".
>
> Jugar contra el Sporting: "Es un partido especial, es un equipo
>   especial. Yo quería volver a jugar ante el Sporting, porque creo que
>   tienen un buen equipo, tienen un buen entrenador y será otro momento
>   especial en mi vida. Ya he jugado ante el Sporting en la Champions
>   League, contra el Benfica también y frente al Oporto. Jugar otra vez
>   ante el Sporting es un privilegio para mí".

....and once applied the substring I get this:

> Defensa del título: "Es un reto, un gran reto, y creo que en el Real Madrid tenemos la oportunidad de volver a ganarla. Sabemos que es una
>   competición muy complicada, pero nada es fácil, así que lo vamos a
>   intentar. Iremos partido a partido y primero pensar en la fase de
>   grupos, porque en mi opinión tenemos un grupo complicado. Veremos cómo
>   se desarrolla la competición. Pienso en positivo: es posible volver a
>   ganarla".Su gran temporada pasada: "En términos de títulos creo que
>   fue posiblemente la mejor temporada de mi carrera.
>
> ```
> <img src="http://www.dom
> ```

How I can prevent 'substring' cut the img tag?

Any help?

Comment: Any knowlegde of regular expressions?

Comment: A little bit, I've used them in some cases but not an expert.

Comment: Can you post an example string and the result you are expecting?

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: use $result = substr(string,start,length); and $re = "/\\<(.)+\\>/m"; 
$str = $result ; 
 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);if(!empty($matches)){//no tag contain in string}

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this code

```
    $result = substr(string,0,250);
     $re = "/\\<(.)+\\>/m";

    preg_match_all($re, $result, $matches);
    if(empty($matches)){
    //no tag contain in string
    echo $result;
    }else{
         preg_match('/\<[a-z]+\>/gm', $string, $sub_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
         $sub_result = substr(string,0, $sub_matches[0][1]);
    echo $sub_result.$matches[0];
    }
```

Above code would check upto 250 character there any tag contain if contain then matches return result and in matches return $matches[0] return string between tag and also append starting string.

Comment: I've tried it but the regular expression does not detect an open tag, I mean, there is a tag like <a href="http://domain.com/uploads/open-source-the and here is the end of the substring.

Comment: put here your testing string

Comment: Using your code I have realized how can i get it. As soon as i have done it, i will post it here as it's more complex that i thought.